# IBM Test Workbench for Worklight - Compound test is not executing all tests

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I'm using IBM Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight 8.6.0 to test a hybrid app for ios. I'm using  an Iphone 4S with ios 7.0.4, and I'm experiencing the following problems:

1 - I'm trying to run a compound test with 4 tests but only two tests are executed. Basically, after finnishing the second test iphone stays in passive mode and the app is not started.

2 - Before the second test of the compound test is started a pop-up appears asking "Open this page in {appName}". Is there any way to prevent this pop-up from appearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - I'm sorry but I have not yet experienced such an issue with compound test.

2 - This issue is a known issue that occurs with Safari.
2a) If you are on an iOS device, you could use another web browser such as Chrome in order to connect to the Workbench.

2b) If you are working on an iOS simulator you can use the native client instead the web one.
You will find the RTWiOS application and its installation script in the downloaded archive.
In order to download the archive, launch Safari on your Mac and browse your workbench url + "/mobile" (i.e: http://*(mtww-ip-address)*:*(port-number)*/mobile

Best Regards, Alexandre.

Comment: It seems that using chrome on the IOS device solved both problems. The pop-up is not appearing anymore and I was already able to run more than 3 test in one compound test. Thanks.

Comment: Good news! Safari open more undesirable windows and popup than Chrome :-)